# Twilio Voice Call State shows "Connected" even if the receiver has not picked up the call

Tags: android, twilio

I am using twilio programmable voice in android. Voice call feature is working perfectly. But the state of an initiated call is showing "connected" even if the dialled party has declined or still haven't answered the call.

I have to get call duration based on it. But the way the listener shows the state of a call, it is not correct.
so how can i get the information/status of a call when it is finally answered by receiver?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can find out the duration that a call lasted by [requesting it from the API and querying the `Duration` property](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/call).

If you need to more accurately show when a call is answered (and not just dialling) in your application, then you can't do that with only the Voice SDK.

Instead, you will need to set a `statusCallback` URL in the [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback) or [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client#attributes-status-callback) that you use in your TwiML application. You can set to [receive a webhook when the call is answered](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client#attributes-status-callback-event). You can then use that webhook event to update your application's UI.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: can you explain more in detail how to get statusCallback in android or how this webhook will notify to specific mobile device?

Comment: You need to set up a server to receive webhooks, they can't be sent directly to your device. You could then send the updates onto the application via a websocket connection or similar.

Comment: @philnash is this answer still accurate today? is there any technical reason why the client can't receive them as all the other events on the device or the connection? or it's just not implemented? if the latter, where can i file a feature request? a client knowing when the other party actually answered is quite useful for UI feedback. In my case i'm using the javascript client, but it seems the issue is the same in android. thank you for all your help!

Comment: btw, from the docs, i would expect this event to be raised when the other party ends, but i think i'm misunderstanding the docs https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#accept-handler or is it a bug?

Comment: @Hilikus This has evolved, and you can get events for ringing and starting the call now. There are caveats though. You need to have set [`enableRingingState` to `true` in Device setup](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#twilio-device) and have [the `answerOnBridge` attribute set to `true` in your `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#answeronbridge).